# CRUD operations in Datagridview bound to SQL Database

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, crud

I have a problem with adding a new row to my datagridview. I want it to be done by Add button. I based my binding on this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx so my code looks almost exactly the same. Is it possible to: first - add a new row to datagridviews bound datasource and then update the database by clicking update button? I managed to get clone of selected row which will be used as a template for the new row. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, I'm not able do something like that
>   dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selected_row); It throws an exception. And I
>   don't know how to insert a row in my database. – user1651521 1 hour
>   ago

You can't add rows directly to the datagrid for a grid that is databound. You have to add the new row to the bound table.

So if you are using the same code as that example, you would add a new record to the DataTable that is the datasource of your bindingsource object. So something like this:

```
private void addButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //I'm assuming your datatable is a member level variable 
    //otherwise you could get it through the grid
    //have the datatable send you back a new row
    DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
    //populate your new row with default data here
    //....
    //add the new row to the data table
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also used foreach loop to copy values to populate my new row.

Comment: I have another problem. I change color of edited cells to green, but after submitting data I want to restore their default color. Can you help me with that?

Comment: When I remove a row from table with table.Rows.RemoveAt(deleted_row_index) in UserDeletedRow event it removes it from the view and the table, but submitting changes to databese doesn't change anything. When I reload the database, there are still those removed rows.

Comment: Is it possible to get name of the table which i loaded to my DGV?

Comment: I think it would be easier to answer those questions in separate posts. For example on the coloring of edited cells, I'd want to see how you are currently coloring an edited cell.

Answer (score 0):

What you could use is the OnRowsAdded event of your DataGridView. Here's a link to this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onrowsadded.aspx. In this event, you could then iterate through each row added and insert them in your database with an Insert statement. I never used that event, but it looks like what you need.

EDIT: I just saw this in your example.

```
private void submitButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // Update the database with the user's changes.
    dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)bindingSource1.DataSource);
}
```

If you have the EditMode activated for your DataGridView and a submit button, wouldn't this work? You must have access to your SqlDataAdapter, so declare it as a global variable and you would be able to use it in your click event of your submit button.

Comment: If you got your data from your database and then put it in a table like in the example you posted, you should still be able to insert your new rows. What is preventing you from inserting new rows in your database?

Comment: Well, I'm not able do something like that                 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(selected_row);
It throws an exception. And I don't know how to insert a row in my database.

Comment: You tried what I wrote under EDIT in my post? I think it could solve your problem. If you get an exception, investigate what is is with a try catch. Post your exception here so we can help you.

Comment: I use submitButton_Click to submit changes, but it doesn't work for adding new rows.